# TKinter Scrollbar and Canvas Configure

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a canvas, containing buttons and attached a scrollbar to the canvas.
When I load this, It looks like this:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyyxl.png)

I can't figure out how to shrink the canvas down to the size of the buttons, as when I do it shrinks the buttons as well. I basically need the canvas to stop a few pixels right of the buttons.

Here is all my code:

```
    def __init__(self, master, user_id, show_logged_in_frame_callback):
        self.master = master
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.show_logged_in_frame_callback = show_logged_in_frame_callback

        # Create a frame to hold the services buttons
        self.services_frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.services_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.services_frame.pack_forget()

        # Create a frame to hold the details
        self.details_frame = tk.Frame(master)
        self.details_frame.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.details_frame.pack_forget()

        # Back button
        self.back_button = ttk.Button(self.master, text="Back", command=self.show_logged_in_frame_callback)
        self.back_button.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor=tk.NE, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.back_button.pack_forget()

        # Label for services
        self.account_page_label = ttk.Label(self.services_frame, text="Your Stored Accounts:", font=('Segoe UI', 18))
        self.account_page_label.pack()

        # Create a Canvas widget to contain the buttons
        self.services_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.services_frame)
        self.services_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)

        # Create a frame inside the Canvas to hold the buttons
        self.services_buttons_frame = ttk.Frame(self.services_canvas)
        self.services_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.services_buttons_frame, anchor=tk.W)

        # Create a Scrollbar and associate it with the Canvas
        self.services_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.services_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.services_canvas.yview)
        self.services_scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)  # Changed side to RIGHT

        # Bind the Canvas to configure the scroll region
        self.services_canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.on_canvas_configure)

        self.service_buttons = []

       

    def on_canvas_configure(self, event):
    # Update the scroll region to match the size of the contents
        self.services_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.services_canvas.bbox("all"))

        # Set the height of the vertical scrollbar to match the canvas
        desired_height = self.services_canvas.winfo_height()
        self.services_scrollbar.config(length=desired_height)

        # Ensure tkinter updates the scrollbar
        self.services_frame.update_idletasks()
        self.services_canvas['yscrollcommand'] = self.services_scrollbar.set  # Reapply yscrollcommand

    def update_services(self, account_ids):
    # Update the services in the frame
        for button in self.service_buttons:
            button.destroy()

        self.service_buttons = []

        for account_id in account_ids:
            user_info = view_account_info(self.user_id, account_id)
            if user_info:
                service_name = user_info["service"].capitalize()
                button = ttk.Button(self.services_buttons_frame, text=service_name, command=lambda id=account_id: self.show_account_details(id), width=10, padding=25)
                button.pack(fill=tk.X)
                self.service_buttons.append(button)
            else:
                print(f"Failed to retrieve account information for Account {account_id}")

        # Update the Canvas to adjust the scroll region
        self.services_canvas.update_idletasks()
```

I tried resizing the canvas but it just cuts the buttons due to them being attached to the canvas. Any solutions?

Comment: If you want to create a Tkinter window (which it appears the code is using) where the size of the window is determined by the size of the buttons, you can do so by not explicitly setting the size of the window.

Comment: If the question is about a canvas and some buttons, I don't think we need all of those labels as part of the example. It would help if you could reduce the code down to a [mcve].

Comment: @D.L I want to create the canvas around the buttons, but currently it creates one larger and when I re-size it, it changes the button sizes. I want to basically wrap it around the button width.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarity in the comment which improves the question.

This procedure would work

- You can create a canvas without specifying the size.
- create button(s)
- once button size is know, configure the canvas to surround (with padding if needed).

here is the code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Canvas Sized to Button")

    # Create a canvas without specifying the size; defaults to 1x1 pixel.
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root)

    # Create a button and add it to the canvas
    button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Click Me")
    canvas.create_window(10, 10, anchor='nw', window=button)

    # Force the update of the button's size calculations
    root.update_idletasks()

    # Now that the button's size is known, configure the canvas size to match
    canvas.config(
        width=button.winfo_reqwidth() + 20, 
        height=button.winfo_reqheight() + 20
        )

    # Pack the canvas after setting its size
    canvas.pack()

    # Start the Tkinter event loop
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Which looks like this:

[image]